# Integral of $\int \sin(x) \cos(3x)dx$

Tags: integration

I want to solve this integral and I know that if I have non parity strong I can set $t=\cos(x) , t=\sin(x)$ but what about the $\cos(3x)$ I don't know now how to set $t$
$$\int \sin(x) \cos(3x)dx$$
Thanks!

Comment: $cos(3x)=4cos(x)^3-3cos(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Use $2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$

or $$\int \sin x\cos3xdx=\int \sin x (4\cos^3x-3\cos x)dx=4\int\cos^3x\sin xdx-3\int\cos x\sin xdx$$

Put $\cos x=u$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the identities

$$ \sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B) $$

$$ \sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B) $$

to find an identity for your integrand.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $$\sin x=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},\cos 3x=\dfrac{e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$I = \int \sin x\, \cos 3x\,dx.$$

Use integration by parts:

$$I = - \cos x\,\cos 3x - \int [-\cos x] [-3 \sin 3x]\, dx.$$

Pulling constants out:

$$I = - \cos x\,\cos 3x - 3\int \cos x\, \sin 3x\, dx.$$

Using integration by parts again (and in the same way, so you do not just reverse what you did):

$$I = - \cos x\,\cos 3x - 3\left[\sin x\, \sin 3x - \int \sin x\, [3 \cos 3x]\, dx \right].$$

Pulling constants out:

$$I = - \cos x\,\cos 3x - 3\sin x\, \sin 3x + 9 \int \sin x\, \cos 3x\, dx.$$

But the last integral is $I$, possibly with a different constant of integration.

$$I = - \cos x\,\cos 3x - 3\sin x\, \sin 3x + 9 I + C.$$

Shuffling around terms,

$$8 I = \cos x\,\cos 3x + 3\sin x\, \sin 3x + C.$$

$$I = \frac{1}{8}\cos x\,\cos 3x + \frac{3}{8}\sin x\, \sin 3x + C.$$

To verify this, differentiate $I$.

$$\frac{dI}{dx} = -\frac{1}{8}\sin x\,\cos 3x  - \frac{3}{8}\cos x\,\sin 3x + \frac{3}{8}\cos x\, \sin 3x + \frac{9}{8}\sin x\, \cos 3x.$$

$$\frac{dI}{dx} = \sin x\,\cos 3x.$$
All right, so this is a boring subject; when I was teaching, this week tended to put my students to sleep. However, note that the definite integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ of this is $0$.  In fact, choose any 2 of $\cos mx$ or $\sin nx$ with $0\le m$ and $1 \le n$.  The definite integral will be $0$ unless you chose the same factor twice.  And this is the start of *Fourier Analysis*.